# Create custom extension Laravel Markdown

Tags: php, laravel, markdown

I used [Laravel Markdown](https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Markdown) to view content. and i want create `custom extension` to render `@image(image_id)` => `<img src="path_to_image"></img>`.

i have used this [Inline Parsing](http://commonmark.thephpleague.com/customization/inline-parsing/) but still didn't understand how to detect the `@image(image_id)`.

Here the example code i have tried:

```
class ImageParser extends AbstractInlineParser
{

    /**
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getCharacters()
    {
        return ['@'];
    }

    /**
     * @param InlineParserContext $inlineContext
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function parse(InlineParserContext $inlineContext)
    {
        $cursor = $inlineContext->getCursor();

        $previous = $cursor->peek(-1);
        if ($previous !== null && $previous !== ' ') {
            return false;
        }

        $previousState = $cursor->saveState();
        $cursor->advance();

        $handle = $cursor->match('/image\((\d+)\)/');
        if (empty($handle)) {
            $cursor->restoreState($previousState);

            return false;
        }

        $imageId = preg_replace("/image\((\d+)\)/", "$1", $handle);
        $image = Image::find($imageId);

        if (is_null($image)) {
            return false;
        }

        $inlineContext->getContainer()->appendChild(new HtmlInline($this->render($image)));

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Render the image figure.
     *
     * @param \PYM\Storage\Image $image
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function render(Image $image)
    {
        $source = empty($image->source) ? null : "<figcaption>{$image->source}</figcaption>";

        return '<figure><img src="' . $image->getUrl('wide') . '" alt="' . $image->alt_tag . '">' . $source . '</figure>';
    }
}
```

I didn't understand how to use `parse()` method. maybe anyone here can explain to me or give an example :)

Comment: Your parser seems to be working correctly.  Is there a specific issue you're having?  Or are you just trying to better understand how this works?

Comment: Specified issue (The result always blank).